# How to find a specific data of consecutive numbers inside an excel spreadsheet column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, spreadsheet, excel-2016

Please help me to find sequence of numbers present in column of a spreadsheet.

I have a large data of 1's and 0's in an excel column, I need to find the sequence of consecutive 1's and 0's in the column. For example, my excel column is given below:

```
0
0
1
1
0
0
1
0
1
0
0
1
1
0
1
1
1
0
0
```

Please assume this as some of my column data, I need to find where are the sequences of 1's and 0's present in the column.
For example, I need to find:

```
0
0
1
1
0
1
```

This sequence of data in the column.
Is there any function for sequence search or something? Please Help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Excel 2019 and O365, it's rather easy using `CONCAT()`:

```
=FIND("001101",CONCAT(A1:A19))
```

However, combining a range of cells prior to these versions of Excel can be tricky. You will quickly get tangled up in syntax like `=MAX((A1:A19=0)*(A2:A20=0)*(A3:A21=1)*(A4:A22=1)*(A5:A23=0)*(A6:A24=1)*(ROW(A1:A19)))` (as an array formula). An UDF is not a bad alternative in this case:

```
Function FINDSEQ(seq As String, rng as Range) As Long
    FINDSEQ = InStr(1, Join(Application.Transpose(rng.Value), ""), seq)
End Function
```

Call like: `=FINDSEQ("001101",A1:A19)`

<sup>***Note** - Better solutions may be found since `Application.Transpose` will have an upperbound limit.*</sup>

Comment: Unfortunately =FINDSEQ function is not available in my Microsoft Excel 2016 version.

Comment: @AashiqShajahan, it's a custom function. Not available to anyone unless the above code is pasted in a module. See [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-custom-functions-in-excel-2f06c10b-3622-40d6-a1b2-b6748ae8231f)

Comment: Thank you. It worked.
Can I find if there are multiple instances of these sequence of numbers in the column?

Comment: Sure, looks like an appropriate new question to me as soon as you have given it a try yourself. You are welcome to open new questions.

Comment: Could you please answer it here itself. Please.....
Shall I edit this question??

Comment: Never change the question so substantially that it would invalidate existing answers. If the OP is answered you are welcome to open new questions.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218665/discussion-between-aashiq-shajahan-and-jvdv).

Answer (score 0):

If the numbers are formated as string you can simply do: `=search("1 1 0 1 0 1";A1)`

Comment: There is an error in the format of the question, Actually the 1's and 0's data I typed was as line by line but it was automatically corrected like this.
That is I assumed that data inside a column.

Comment: Formula will be better for me, because I am not much used to VBA.