# How to search for a specific data of consecutive numbers in a column of an excel even if multiple instances are present

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, spreadsheet, excel-2016

How can I find multiple instances of presence of consecutive numbers in a column of big data of 1's and 0's in excel spreadsheet.
For example, my excel column is given below:

```
0                    
0  
1   
1   
0  
0  
1  
0  
1   
0  
0  
1  
1   
0  
1  
1  
1  
0  
0  
1   
1    
0    
0  
1   
0
```

Please assume this as some of my column data, I need to find wherever the sequences of 1's and 0's present in the column.

I defined a function for finding single instance as below:

```
Function FINDSEQ(seq As String, rng as Range) As Long
    FINDSEQ = InStr(1, Join(Application.Transpose(rng.Value), ""), seq)
End Function
```

But I couldn't find how to find multiple instances if present.
For Example, I need to find:

```
1    
1  
0   
0   
1  
0
```

as the sequence of consecutive numbers, what change should I do?
Here 1 1 0 0 1 0 is present two times, but based on the above defined function I could only find a single instance.

Comment: There are a couple of questions with answers on here that show some solutions, perhaps check those out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was hoping you would give it a bit more of a try yourself first after your previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63110367/9758194). I'd also go with the first parameter of `InStr`, but a little different to @JMP:

```
Function FINDSEQ(rng As Range, seq As String) As String

Dim x As Long, y As Long: x = 1
Do While InStr(x, Join(Application.Transpose(rng.Value), ""), seq) > 0
    y = InStr(x, Join(Application.Transpose(rng.Value), ""), seq)
    If FINDSEQ = "" Then
        FINDSEQ = y
    Else
        FINDSEQ = FINDSEQ & "," & y
    End If
    x = y + 1
Loop

End Function
```

The function has now also changed from `Long` type to `String`.

Comment: I am really sorry, I am not good at VBA, I just copy pasted this code to VBA and called the function like you answered in my previous question, But it shows #VALUE! error.

Comment: You did `=FINDSEQ(A1:A25,"110010")`? Worked fine for me. Btw, remove the older function first.

Comment: Previously I did:
=FINDSEQ("110010",A1:A25), it didn't worked.

Now It is perfectly fine, Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Aashiq Shajahan: So, you need the overlapping occurrences to be fount, too. In such a case, we hare tick the code left side check box, in order to make it **accepted answer**. In this way, somebody else searching for something similar will know that the code works...

Answer (score 2):

Try the next function, please:

```
Function FINDSEQ(seq As String, rng As Range) As Long
 FINDSEQ = UBound(Split(Join(Application.Transpose(rng.Value), ""), seq))
End Function
```

And call it in the next way:

```
Sub testFINDSEQ()
  Dim sh As Worksheet, rng As Range
  
  Set sh = ActiveSheet
  Set rng = sh.Range("A1:A25")
  Debug.Print FINDSEQ("110010", rng)
End Sub
```

Or from a cell (like UDF):

```
=FINDSEQ("110010",A1:A25)
```

Do not forget to delete your already existing function

Comment: Upvoted, OP is not clear if he wants to know instances or positions. I think positions because of the original UDF. Be aware that you are not finding overlapping hits. +

Comment: @JvdV: He's not too clear, indeed. I asked a long clarification comment, but I deduced that he was unsatisfied with his UDF function result... He wanted more occurrences. That's why I deleted my comment supposing that my last understanding would be correct. In such a case, I think that the overlapping will not count . Now, only he will be able to clarify the issue... :)

Answer (score 2):

Add a `sp` (starting position) parameter to the `FINDSEQ` function:

```
Function FINDSEQ(seq As String, rng As Range, sp As Integer) As Long
    FINDSEQ = InStr(sp, Join(Application.Transpose(rng.Value), ""), seq)
End Function
```

and then continue the search from the immediate next position from any found matching string:

```
newpos=FINDSEQ(1)

Do While newpos>0
    Debug.Print newpos
    newpos=FINDSEQ(newpos+1)
Loop
```